# DataTables and JSON array of objects

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

I am trying to place JSON response from an API call into a DataTables dataTable. I am struggling to find a way to get the data to go into the Data Table.

in the data section (get the data object). I have tried passing data.fault_codes and data.fault_codes[0].  everytime it comes back as undefined or errors out.

Here is my DataTable:

```
$('#faultCodes').DataTable({
    data: data,  // Get the data object
    columns: [
        { 'data': 'fault_code.code_label' },
        { 'data': 'fault_code.code_description' },
        { 'data': 'fault_code.source_address_label' },
        { 'data': 'fault_code.status' },
        { 'data': 'fault_code.first_observed_at' },
        { 'data': 'fault_code.last_observed_at' },
        { 'data': 'fault_code.type' },
        { 'data': 'fault_code.fmi' },
    ],
    order: [[4, "asc"]]
});
```

Here is JSON String:

```
{ "fault_codes": [ { "fault_code": { "id": 173164, "code_label": "SID-85", "code_description": "Engine Oil Burn Valve", "source_address_label": "Engine #1", "status": "open", "first_observed_at": "2017-04-17T07:08:51Z", "last_observed_at": "2017-04-19T23:41:17Z", "type": "intermittent", "fmi": 3, "eld_device": { "id": 4144, "identifier": "99999999", "model": "lbb-1" }, "vehicle": { "id": 4565, "number": "301", "year": "2016", "make": "Demo", "model": "Vehicle", "vin": "WP0AB2966NS458669", "metric_units": false } } }, { "fault_code": { "id": 173165, "code_label": "SPN-6926", "code_description": "SCR System Cleaning Inhibited Due to Low Exhaust Temperature", "source_address_label": "Hitch Control", "status": "open", "first_observed_at": "2017-04-17T07:08:51Z", "last_observed_at": "2017-04-19T23:41:17Z", "type": "constant", "fmi": 3, "eld_device": { "id": 4144, "identifier": "99999999", "model": "lbb-1" }, "vehicle": { "id": 4565, "number": "301", "year": "2016", "make": "Demo", "model": "Vehicle", "vin": "WP0AB2966NS458669", "metric_units": false } } } ], "per_page": 25, "page_no": 1, "total": 2 }
```

[image]

```js
   $.ajax({
        "url": "/api....,
        "type": "GET",
        "datatype": 'json',
        "success": function (data) {
            console.log(data.fault_codes);
            $('#faultCodes').DataTable({
                data: data.fault_codes,  // Get the data object
                columns: [
                    { 'data': 'fault_code.code_label' },
                    { 'data': 'fault_code.code_description' },
                    { 'data': 'fault_code.source_address_label' },
                    { 'data': 'fault_code.status' },
                    { 'data': 'fault_code.first_observed_at' },
                    { 'data': 'fault_code.last_observed_at' },
                    { 'data': 'fault_code.type' },
                    { 'data': 'fault_code.fmi' },
                ],
                order: [[4, "asc"]]
            });
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="faultCodes" class="table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code Label</th>
      <th>Code Description</th>
      <th>Source</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>First Observed</th>
      <th>Last Observed</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>FMI</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I assume you load your JSON into a variable called `data` (not shown in the question). In that case, your table `data` option needs to be this: `data: data.fault_codes`. This tells DataTables where the array in your `data` variable is located, which contains your data rows in the JSON structure. Then in each of your `column.data` options, use dot notation to access the value inside the `fault_code` object - for example: `{ 'data': 'fault_code.code_label' },`.

Comment: If that does not work, can you provide a [mre] - and show us how you are loading your JSON?

Comment: That stopped it from error but did not load any data. i'll try and do an example quick

Comment: Can you show how you are loading your JSON? When I assume it is loaded into a variable called `data`, then your code works for me without any errors.

Comment: thanks for the "working" example, but it is still not showing how you load your JSON...

Comment: I added the full call to the API, I only have the data local so not sure how to publish the API call.

Comment: If I do console.log(data); it will show all the JSON Data that is being returned. If I do console.log(data.fault_codes), the console response's with undefined.